# How to display only errors in the location list?

Tags: vim, macvim, syntastic

In **vim**, **Syntastic** always shows the *warnings* with the *errors*. However, I don't want the *warnings* to be displayed. Is there a config to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { "level" : "warnings" }`.

Read `:h syntastic_quiet_messages` for more info.

Comment: Thanks Marth, I did read the **documentation** and I did find this config option. However, I mistakenly concluded that I have to put the things that I want to appear in the `level` section. As a result I used `error` instead of `warning`. I was so sure that I didn't bother to try `warning` instead :).